# Get root element and all descendants MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I should get root element with all descendants from that structure:

```
rootA
    rootB
        child1
    rootC
        child2
    chold3
rootD
    child4
```

RESULT:

```
Root| Child

rootA child1
rootA child2
rootA child3
rootD child4
```

I understand, that firstly I should get root elements without parents:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        rootId,
        childId
  FROM
        root
            WHERE rootId IS NULL
```

But I dont know the next step.
Do you have some variants?

Thanks!

Comment: what happened? did I manage to help you?

Answer (score 0):

This is done with a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
;WITH cte_hierarchy AS (
    -- get all roots
    SELECT DISTINCT
        rootId, childId
    FROM
        root
    WHERE rootId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- this is the recursive part
    -- get all children for all roots, including children of children, etc.
    SELECT
        child.rootId, child.childId
    FROM root child
    JOIN cte_hierarchy parent ON parent.childid=child.rootid
)
SELECT * FROM cte_hierarchy;
```

Comment: but if i got data from 3 tables (many-to-many), how to use CTE in this case?

Comment: update your example for a more accurate answer, please. In general you should be able to `JOIN` all tables and select required fields